# Function.call(someInstance,args) for methodes. Ignores first arg

Tags: actionscript-3, call, this

In as3 there is a flexible way to change object instance, when calling it.
call or apply members of Function object can be called with specific first arg, and reference say us, that this first arg will be "this" pointer inside function. But i've found it wrong.

I'v write little test, listed below.

```
public class Test 
{
  private var name:String = "default";
  public var test3:Function = test;
  public var test2:Function = function()
  {
    trace(this.name);
  }

  public function Test(name:String) 
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public function test():void
  {
    trace(this.name);
  }
}
```

and tested it.

```
var tmp:Test = new Test("default");
tmp.test();  //out default
tmp.test.call(new Test("new"));  //out default

tmp.test2(); //out default
tmp.test2.call(new Test("new2")); //out new2

tmp.test3(); //out default
tmp.test3.call(new Test("new3")); //out default
```

So, in anonymous function call we can get right output, but not in case of member function. 
maybe it's becouse of ambiguous "this" pointer, that should reffer real object instance for correct work, maybe smth else. I dont now, and as3 reference didnt't describe smth about it.

Finally list of questions:

1. Why so? By me, it's very strange, and looks like undefined behaviour;
2. How i can achieve that functionality? How to deceive test function like anonymous one? Isn't it call methode target?

It isn't very important, but I'll be glad any good answer. Thanks!

P.S. sorry for my English.

//EDITED: added this statement to all "name" references. Nothing changes.

Comment: change your trace statement in the test function to trace(this.name);

Comment: Oh, nothing will change. I checked it out. In anonymous, this may be necessary, i think, due to closure creation otherwise (I have some problems in understanding anonymous function behaviour). In private method there is no closures and another variants, so name is equivalent to "this.name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When invoking the [[Call]] property, the behavior is different for
>   different types of closures. A closure is an object that contains a
>   reference to a method, and the [[Call]] property acts differently
>   depending on whether it is a function, method, or class closure. A
>   function closure is one that is of a global method that isn't
>   associated with any instance of a class. A method closure contains an
>   instance method of a class, and will always remember its original
>   "this" value.
>
> If the closure is a function closure, then the first argument passed
>   to [[Call]] is passed on to the method and gets used as the "this"
>   value. If the first argument is null or undefined, then the global
>   object will be used as the "this" value for the method.
>
> If the closure is a method closure, then the first argument of
>   [[Call]] will be ignored, and the saved "this" value for the method
>   closure will be passed to the method as the first argument. A method
>   closure records what its original "this" value was and always uses
>   that instead of the first argument to [[Call]].
>
> If the closure is a class closure, and there is 1 argument passed to
>   [[Call]] (in addition to the "this" argument), then the call is
>   treated as a type conversion, and the argument will be coerced to the
>   type represented by the closure.

http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/AVM2/2.4+Method+invocation+notes

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! I would have never thought to look there. I don't even know about the existence of such a reference. Very helpful!